# 301 subfolder redirect but want old URL to remain in address bar

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I am subfolder redirecting from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/folder`

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/website/index.php [R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Except for one thing, this is 95% working.

The root URL redirects to the `/website` subfolder.
Both `www.example.com` and `example.com` resolve and are redirected.
And `www` is prefixed to `example.com/website`.

However, the final thing I want to do is make the URL remain in the browser window, so that if a user clicks a bookmark, or types in `(www)example.com`, then the visual served content is from the redirected `index.php`, but in the browser address bar they still see `www.example.com`.

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains on the same account? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Server configuration questions are off topic here and belong on serverfault.com: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Server Fault participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.

Comment: @Rob This question is perfectly on-topic for webmasters - this is _userland_ config that directly relates to running a website (aka URL rewriting). Unless you are managing your own server (a sysadmin) then strictly speaking this would be off-topic on ServerFault.

Comment: @w3dk So you are saying .htaccess files are not Apache configuration?

Comment: @w3dk Actually, given that it's URL rewriting and, specifically, userland, I see your point but I'll have to think about whether I agree it's on topic or not.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the same URL in the address bar, you need an *internal rewrite*, as opposed to an *external redirect* (that's the `R=301` bit).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ website/index.php [L]
```

Notice that the `R` flag is removed from the `RewriteRule` and the *substitution* is now relative, not absolute. (An absolute URL-path would *implicitly* trigger a redirect.)

In the code you posted, the `RewriteBase` directive is not required. Neither is the second `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `REQUEST_URI` - I've moved the URL check to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead, which is more efficient. The `NC` (`nocase`) flag is also not required on the `RewriteRule` in this instance.

Unless you have multiple domains on your account then the first `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `HTTP_HOST` is also not required.

And unless this is intended to work without mod_rewrite installed then you should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper as well.

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing, as the previous 301 redirect will have been cached.

Note that this is a single rewrite from `www.example.com/` to `www.example.com/website/index.php`. Any other URL is not rewritten/redirected. So, any internal links will need to contain the actual root-relative (or absolute) URLs.